# Need example on functional dependency

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Can i get example on functional dependency in database concepts with example?

I understood that when a particular column is dependent on another column then it is called as functional dependent on other one.But i am not able to visulize with example..plz help me out

Answer (score 2):

Let R be
NewStudent(stuId, lastName, major, credits, status, socSecNo)

FDs in R include

```
{stuId}→{lastName}, but not the reverse
{stuId} →{lastName, major, credits, status, socSecNo, stuId}
{socSecNo} →{stuId, lastName, major, credits, status, socSecNo}
{credits}→{status}, but not {status}→{credits}
```

ZipCode→AddressCity

```
16652 is Huntingdon’s ZIP
```

ArtistName→BirthYear

```
Picasso was born in 1881
```

Autobrand→Manufacturer, Engine type

```
Pontiac is built by General Motors with gasoline engine
```

Author, Title→PublDate

```
Shakespeare’s Hamlet was published in 1600
```

Trivial Functional Dependency

The FD X→Y is trivial if set {Y} is a subset of set {X}

Examples: If A and B are attributes of R,

```
{A}→{A}
{A,B} →{A}
{A,B} →{B}
{A,B} →{A,B}
```

are all trivial FDs and will not contribute to the evaluation of normalization.
 for more details..check source.
source -  http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/dbms/funcdep.htm